# Searching product for description and keywords in separate table

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables, one holding products, and the other one holding keywords;

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
      `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `title`, `description`) 
    VALUES
      ('1', 'Product 1', 'Vacuum cleaner'),
      ('2', 'Product 2', 'Refrigerator'),
      ('3', 'Product 3', 'Mixer'),
      ('4', 'Product 4', 'Stereo');

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keywords` (
      `keyid` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `productid` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `keyword` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`keyid`)
    ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `keywords` (`keyid`, `productid`, `keyword`) 
    VALUES
      ('1', '1', 'white matte'),
      ('2', '1', '100W'),
      ('3', '3', 'shiny black'),
      ('4', '3', '15W'),
      ('5', '4', '350W');
```

| ID | Title | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product 1 | Vacuum cleaner |
| 2 | Product 2 | Refrigerator |
| 3 | Product 3 | Mixer |

| ProductID | Keyword |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | White matte |
| 1 | 100W |
| 3 | Shiny black |
| 3 | 25W |

Some products will have keywords, others won't.

Now I'd like to query products in a way that the title, description and all keywords are searched.

I'd want to search for "white 100W" for instance, in order to find product 1 in this case.

I put all search terms in an array and have this kind of query:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.title 
      FROM products AS p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN keywords AS k 
    ON k.productID = p.ID 
 WHERE
     (p.title LIKE '%white%' 
    OR p.description LIKE '%white%' 
    OR k.keyword LIKE '%cleaner%') 
   AND 
     (p.title LIKE '%100W%' 
    OR p.description LIKE '%100W%' 
    OR k.keyword LIKE '%100W%') 
 GROUP 
    BY p.ID
```

**UPDATE: here's an SQLfiddle**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8114e9/2
which returns zero rows because only the first keyword is taken into account in the join. I want it to look through all the keywords though (in reality often 20-30).

What's the most efficient way to solve this? I tried looking into GROUP_CONCAT(all keywords) AS keywords and HAVING keywords LIKE ... but that doesn't work when there are no keywords or when I'm simply searching part of the description.

I also looked into a UNION, basically doing

```
SELECT ... FROM products WHERE title LIKE ... OR description LIKE ...
UNION
SELECT ... FROM keywords WHERE keyword LIKE ...
```

But that seems to be much less efficient, with long execution times.
What's the most efficient solution here?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry, I've added an SQL fiddle

Comment: If you remove ORs isn't it basically filtering `WHERE p.title LIKE '%white%' AND p.title LIKE '%100W%'`? And since you don't have a `title` value that contain either, it won't return anything. If you replace `AND` with another `OR`, [this is what happen](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8114e9/6)

Answer (score 1):

A `LIKE` with a wildcard at the beginning cannot use any indexes. So for `product` you'll have a full table scan anyways. You solution using a disjunction of disjunctions therefore is well enough.

For the `keywords` you could use `EXISTS` with a correlated subquery. An index on `keywords (productid)` or `keywords (productid, keyword)` might help to limit the costly scan for the `LIKE` on the keywords really belonging to the product.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.title
       FROM products p
       WHERE <disjunction for p.title>
              OR
              <disjunction for p.description>
               OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM keywords k
                                 WHERE k.productid = p.id
                                       AND (<disjunction for k.keyword>);
```

But might want to refactor completely and try to use [full-text indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) and [search functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html) instead.